# office365 management activity api no content available to download

Tags: python, azure, office365, office365-restapi

I am just trying to create a test app which can download AD logs(looking for logins/logout specifically) using the python Management activity api . I wish to use client credentials flow for this and have uploaded a certificate for the same. Authentication is successful  and I get the JWT token.

I am able to subscribe to Azure Ad content.

```
GET /api/v1.0/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/activity/feed/subscriptions/list HTTP/1.1
[{u'status': u'enabled', u'webhook': None, u'contentType': u'Audit.Exchange'}, {u'status': u'enabled', u'webhook': None, u'contentType': u'Audit.AzureActiveDirectory'}]
```

But there is no content available for me to download.

```
GET /api/v1.0/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/activity/feed/subscriptions/content?contentType=Audit.AzureActiveDirectory HTTP/1.1
```

This yields an empty response with 200 ok.

I am wondering what is missing at my end to be able to download the logs.Has anybody faced similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to donwload some audit logs of Azure AD as the offical document [Azure Active Directory audit report events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-audit-events) said as the AAD audit report events.

So you need to follow the offical tutorial [Getting started with the Azure Active Directory reporting API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-api-getting-started) to get these audit report events. But according to the [audit api reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-api-audit-reference), the API Endpoint should be like as below, not your current used.

> https://graph.windows.net/contoso.com/activities/audit?api-version=beta

As references in [the get started tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-api-getting-started), although almost sample codes written in PowerShell, there is [a python sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-api-audit-samples#python-script) which you can refer to, and then follow to rewrite others in Python easily.

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Peter, I am looking for all sign in events and the audit log doesn't have that information. Only suspicious signins are reported via signins api (https://graph.windows.net/madzcar.onmicrosoft.com/activities/signinEvents?api-version=beta  ) and that also is premium feature not available for developer edition. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office-365/office-365-management-activity-api-reference#retrieving-content is exactly what i am looking for since it gives me login events for all apps under office365. However as I said above, there is  no content  available for download